# Magento CE - qtyincrements

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, qty-increment

My question involves how the qty increment message is displayed on the frontend.

What I want to do is only display the message found in the qtyincrement.phtml file when the qty increment is greater than one. If the item is purchasable in a quantity of 1 I don't want the message displayed. What is the best way to achieve this?

I am currently on version 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `app/design/frontend/[PACKAGE]/[THEME]/template/cataloginventory/qtyincrements.phtml` and add another condition into the if statement like so:

```
<?php if ($this->getProductQtyIncrements() && $this->getProductQtyIncrements() > 1) : ?>
```